# Transfer objects on per field basis over network

Tags: c#, .net, networking, serialization, multiplayer

I need to transfer .NET objects (with hierarchy) over network (multiplayer game). To save bandwidth, I'd like to transfer only fields (and/or properties) that changes, so fields that won't change won't transfer.

I also need some mechanism to match proper objects on the other client side (global object identifier...something like object ID?)

I need some suggestions how to do it.
Would you use reflection? (performance is critical)
I also need mechanism to transfer IList deltas (added objects, removed objects).

How is MMO networking done, do they transfer whole objects?
(maybe my idea of per field transfer is stupid)

EDIT:
To make it clear: I've already got mechanism to track changes (lets say every field has property, setter adds field to some sort of list or dictionary, which contains changes - structure is not final now).

I don't know how to serialize this list and then deserialize it on other client. And mostly how to do it effectively and how to update proper objects.

There's about one hundred of objects, so I'm trying avoid situation when I would write special function for each object. Decorating fields or properties with attributes would be ok (for example to specify serializer, field id or something similar).

More about objects: Each object has 5 fields in average. Some object are inherited from other.

Thank you for all answeres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach; don't try to serialize complex data changes: instead, send just the **actual commands** to apply (in a terse form), for example:

```
move 12432 134, 146
remove 25727
```

(which would move 1 object and remove another).

You would then apply the commands at the receiver, allowing for a full resync if they get out of sync.

I don't propose you would actually use text for this - that is just to make the example clearer.

One nice thing about this: it also provides "replay" functionality for free.

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest way to track dirty fields is to have it as a key feature of your object model, I.e. with a "fooDirty" field for every data field "foo", that you set to true in the "set" (if the value differs). This could also be twinned with conditional serialization, perhaps the "ShouldSerializeFoo()" pattern observed by a few serializers. I'm not aware of any libraries that match *exactly* what you describe (unless we include DataTable, but ... think of the kittens!)

Perhaps another issue is the need to track all the objects for merge during deserialization; that by itself doesn't come for free.

All things considered, though, I think you could do something alon the above lines (fooDirty/ShouldSerializeFoo) and use protobuf-net as the serializer, because (importantly) that supports both conditional serialization and merge. I would also suggest an interface like:

```
ISomeName {
    int Key {get;}
    bool IsDirty {get;}
}
```

The IsDrty would allow you to quickly check all your objects for those with changes, then add the key to a stream, then the (conditional) serialization. The caller would read the key, obtain the object needed (or allocate a new one with that key), and then use the merge-enabled deserialize (passing in the existing/new object).

Not a full walk-through, but *if it was me*, that is the approach I would be looking at. Note: the addition/removal/ordering of objects in child-collections is a tricky area, that might need thought.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just say up front that Marc Gravell's suggestion is really the correct approach. He glosses over some *minor* details, like conflict resolution (you might want to read up on Leslie Lamport's work. He's basically spent his whole career describing different approaches to dealing with conflict resolution in distributed systems), but the idea is sound.

If you do want to transmit state snapshots, instead of procedural descriptions of state changes, then I suggest you look into building snapshot diffs as prefix trees. The basic idea is that you construct a hierarchy of objects and fields. When you change a group of fields, any common prefix they have is only included once. This might look like:

```
world -> player 1 -> lives: 1
...               -> points: 1337
...               -> location -> X: 100
...                           -> Y: 32
...   -> player 2 -> lives: 3
```

(everything in a "..." is only transmitted once).

Answer (score 1):

It is not logical to transfer only changed fields because you would be wasting your time on detecting which fields changed and which didn't and how to reconstruct on the receiver's side which will add a lot of latency to your game and make it unplayable online.

My proposed solution is for you to decompose your objects to the minimum and sending these small objects which is fast. Also, you can use compression to reduce bandwidth usage.

For the Object ID, you can use a static ID which increases when you construct a new Object.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: Tracking dirty fields can be pretty cheap, depending on how much you are happy to have it "invade" into the object model, and could achieve significant serialization savings.

Comment: But How would the receiver know what fields it is receiving unless he does some extra work to identify the dirty. That is my point, there is a "small" extra work on the sender side and a "small" extra work on the receiver's side. Combine them, is it really that much saving at the end??

Comment: the receiver knows that by the field identification, which already exists (in te example I give, merge in this way is fundamentally supported by the protocol, but as an analogy: in XML it would be "the element name"). Given that the receiver *already* has to do this, there is exactly zero cost at the receiver. At the sender, checking a bool is much cheaper than actually serializing anything - so it would be **cheaper** at the sender most of the time, with a very very slight increase (barely measurable) in the case web everythig is dirty.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this by hand. Automatically keeping track of property and instance changes in a hierarchy of objects is going to be very slow compared to anything crafted by hand.

If you decide to try it out anyway, I would try to map your objects to a DataSet and use its built in modification tracking mechanisms.

I still think you should do this by hand, though.